# Detect open or closed eye using openCV in python

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, face-detection, haar-classifier

I'm trying to detect whether the user's eyes are open or closed in a live video, using haar cascade algorithm in python.
Unfortunately it doesn't work well.

I understood that "haarcascade_eye.xml" is used to detect open eyes and "haarcascade_lefteye_2splits" is used to detect an eye (closed or open).

I wanted to compare the open eyes and eyes in general in the video but it makes false recognition of closed eyes. Are there other\more ways to improve it?

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_eye.xml')
lefteye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_lefteye_2splits.xml')

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
   ret, img = cap.read()
   gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
   faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)

for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
    cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255, 0, 0), 2)
    # regions of interest
    roi_gray = gray[y:y + h, (x+w)/2:x + w]
    roi_color = img[y:y + h, (x+w)/2:x + w]
    eye = 0
    openEye = 0
    counter = 0
    openEyes = eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(roi_gray)
    AllEyes = lefteye_cascade.detectMultiScale(roi_gray)
    for (ex, ey, ew, eh) in openEyes:
        openEye += 1
        cv2.rectangle(roi_color, (ex, ey), (ex + ew, ey + eh), (0, 255, 0),2)

    for (ex, ey, ew, eh) in AllEyes:
        eye += 1
        cv2.rectangle(roi_color, (ex, ey), (ex + ew, ey + eh), (0, 0, 40),2)

    if (openEye != eye):
        print ('alert')

cv2.imshow('img', img)

k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
if k == 27:
    break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: found a solution- using DLib library and recognizing facial landmarks :)

Answer (score 3):

eventually I used DLib library for recognizing facial landmarks :)

Answer (score 0):

Check this out. it gives the eye status. change the threshold according to lightning condictions.
resource : https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/04/24/eye-blink-detection-opencv-python-dlib/

```
# import the necessary packages
from scipy.spatial import distance as dist
from imutils.video import FileVideoStream
from imutils.video import VideoStream
from imutils import face_utils
import numpy as np
import argparse
import imutils
import time
import dlib
import cv2


def eye_aspect_ratio(eye):
    # compute the euclidean distances between the two sets of
    # vertical eye landmarks (x, y)-coordinates
    A = dist.euclidean(eye[1], eye[5])
    B = dist.euclidean(eye[2], eye[4])

    # compute the euclidean distance between the horizontal
    # eye landmark (x, y)-coordinates
    C = dist.euclidean(eye[0], eye[3])

    # compute the eye aspect ratio
    ear = (A + B) / (2.0 * C)

    # return the eye aspect ratio
    return ear

# frames the eye must be below the threshold
EYE_AR_THRESH = 0.35
EYE_AR_CONSEC_FRAMES = 3

# initialize the frame counters and the total number of blinks
COUNTER = 0
TOTAL = 0

# initialize dlib's face detector (HOG-based) and then create
# the facial landmark predictor
print("[INFO] loading facial landmark predictor...")
detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()
predictor = dlib.shape_predictor("shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat")

# grab the indexes of the facial landmarks for the left and
# right eye, respectively
(lStart, lEnd) = face_utils.FACIAL_LANDMARKS_IDXS["left_eye"]
(rStart, rEnd) = face_utils.FACIAL_LANDMARKS_IDXS["right_eye"]

vs = VideoStream(src=0).start()
# vs = VideoStream(usePiCamera=True).start()
time.sleep(1.0)

# loop over frames from the video stream
while True:
    # if this is a file video stream, then we need to check if
    # there any more frames left in the buffer to process

    # grab the frame from the threaded video file stream, resize
    # it, and convert it to grayscale
    # channels)
    frame = vs.read()
    frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=450)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # detect faces in the grayscale frame
    rects = detector(gray, 0)

    # loop over the face detections
    for rect in rects:
        # determine the facial landmarks for the face region, then
        # convert the facial landmark (x, y)-coordinates to a NumPy
        # array
        shape = predictor(gray, rect)
        shape = face_utils.shape_to_np(shape)

        # extract the left and right eye coordinates, then use the
        # coordinates to compute the eye aspect ratio for both eyes
        leftEye = shape[lStart:lEnd]
        rightEye = shape[rStart:rEnd]
        leftEAR = eye_aspect_ratio(leftEye)
        rightEAR = eye_aspect_ratio(rightEye)

        # average the eye aspect ratio together for both eyes
        ear = (leftEAR + rightEAR)

        # compute the convex hull for the left and right eye, then
        # visualize each of the eyes
        leftEyeHull = cv2.convexHull(leftEye)
        rightEyeHull = cv2.convexHull(rightEye)
        cv2.drawContours(frame, [leftEyeHull], -1, (0, 255, 0), 1)
        cv2.drawContours(frame, [rightEyeHull], -1, (0, 255, 0), 1)

        # check to see if the eye aspect ratio is below the blink
        # threshold, and if so, increment the blink frame counter
        if ear < EYE_AR_THRESH:
            cv2.putText(frame, "Eye: {}".format("close"), (10, 30),
                    cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (0, 0, 255), 2)
            cv2.putText(frame, "EAR: {:.2f}".format(ear), (300, 30),
                    cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (0, 0, 255), 2)


        # otherwise, the eye aspect ratio is not below the blink
        # threshold
        else:
            cv2.putText(frame, "Eye: {}".format("Open"), (10, 30),
                    cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (0, 0, 255), 2)
            cv2.putText(frame, "EAR: {:.2f}".format(ear), (300, 30),
                    cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (0, 0, 255), 2)

    # draw the total number of blinks on the frame along with
    # the computed eye aspect ratio for the frame

    # show the frame
    cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

    # if the `q` key was pressed, break from the loop
    if key == ord("q"):
        break

# do a bit of cleanup
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
vs.stop()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Import the necessary packages 
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from EAR_calculator import *
from imutils import face_utils 
from imutils.video import VideoStream
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animate
from matplotlib import style 
import imutils 
import dlib
import time 
import cv2 
from playsound import playsound
from scipy.spatial import distance as dist
import os 
import csv
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

# Declare a constant which will work as the threshold for EAR value, below which it will be regared as a blink 
EAR_THRESHOLD = 0.2
# Declare another costant to hold the consecutive number of frames to consider for a blink 
CONSECUTIVE_FRAMES = 20 
# Another constant which will work as a threshold for MAR value
MAR_THRESHOLD = 14

# Now, intialize the dlib's face detector model as 'detector' and the landmark predictor model as 'predictor'
detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector() 
predictor = dlib.shape_predictor("shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat")

# Grab the indexes of the facial landamarks for the left and right eye respectively 
(lstart, lend) = face_utils.FACIAL_LANDMARKS_IDXS["left_eye"]
(rstart, rend) = face_utils.FACIAL_LANDMARKS_IDXS["right_eye"]
(mstart, mend) = face_utils.FACIAL_LANDMARKS_IDXS["mouth"]

image = cv2.imread("images/raja_sleepy.jpg")

gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
# Detect faces 
rects = detector(image, 1)

if len(rects)==1:
    
    for (i, rect) in enumerate(rects):
        shape = predictor(gray, rect)
        # Convert it to a (68, 2) size numpy array 
        shape = face_utils.shape_to_np(shape)
        # Draw a rectangle over the detected face 
        (x, y, w, h) = face_utils.rect_to_bb(rect) 
        cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)    
        # Put a number 
        
        leftEye = shape[lstart:lend]
        rightEye = shape[rstart:rend] 
        mouth = shape[mstart:mend]
        # Compute the EAR for both the eyes 
        leftEAR = eye_aspect_ratio(leftEye)
        rightEAR = eye_aspect_ratio(rightEye)

        # Take the average of both the EAR
        EAR = (leftEAR + rightEAR) / 2.0
        #live datawrite in csv
        
        # Compute the convex hull for both the eyes and then visualize it
        leftEyeHull = cv2.convexHull(leftEye)
        rightEyeHull = cv2.convexHull(rightEye)
        # Draw the contours 
        cv2.drawContours(image, [leftEyeHull], -1, (0, 255, 0), 1)
        cv2.drawContours(image, [rightEyeHull], -1, (0, 255, 0), 1)
        cv2.drawContours(image, [mouth], -1, (0, 255, 0), 1)
        
        MAR = mouth_aspect_ratio(mouth)
            # Check if EAR < EAR_THRESHOLD, if so then it indicates that a blink is taking place 
            # Thus, count the number of frames for which the eye remains closed 
        if EAR < EAR_THRESHOLD: 
            cv2.drawContours(image, [leftEyeHull], -1, (0, 0, 255), 1)
            cv2.drawContours(image, [rightEyeHull], -1, (0, 0, 255), 1)
            cv2.putText(image, "Sleepy", (270, 30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (0, 0, 255), 2)
        else:
            FRAME_COUNT = 0        
            # Check if the person is yawning
        if MAR > MAR_THRESHOLD:
            cv2.drawContours(image, [mouth], -1, (0, 0, 255), 1) 
            cv2.putText(image, "Yawn ", (270, 30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (0, 0, 255), 2)
            
    cv2.imshow("Output", image)
    cv2.waitKey(0)

elif len(rects)==0:
    print("Face not available")

else:
    print("Multiple face detected")
```